# Having problems rewriting a folder location with Mod Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the below code in my `.htaccess` file, this all works fine.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*)$ $2.php?rewrite_params=$1&page_url=$2

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*(.*) [OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|[|%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|[|%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

RewriteRule ^stores/([0-9a-z.-]+)/?$ shop.php?shop_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^stores/([0-9a-z.-]+)/ajax_files/watch_item\.php$ ajax_files/watch_item.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^stores/([0-9a-z.-]+)/ajax_files/save_field\.php$ ajax_files/save_field.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^stores/([0-9a-z.-]+)/images/form-cb-icons\.png$ images/form-cb-icons.png [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^group-break/([0-9]+)/[0-9a-z.-]+/?$ group_break.php?cb_id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^group-breaks/([a-z]+)-[a-z-]+/?$ group_breaks.php?tab=$1 [L,NC]
```

However I'm trying to add a new rule at the bottom which is this:

```
RewriteRule ^billing/client/login/?$ login.php [L,NC]
```

However this doesn't appear to work. Not sure if it matters or not but the `billing` directory also has a `.htaccess` file which may be overwriting it? The contents of that file are below:

```
<Files ~ "\.(pdt)$">
   order deny,allow
   deny from all
</Files>

# Protect against Clickjacking
#Header append X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"

RewriteEngine on

# Force HTTPS
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=307,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/install.php$
RewriteRule install.php %1/install/ [R=301,L]
```

I wanted to put my code in the root `.htaccess` file as the one inside the `billing` dir is for other software which may get overwritten.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your guess is right. If `/billing/.htaccess` exists with some rewrite rules then you need to add this rule in `/billing/.htaccess` file:

```
<Files ~ "\.(pdt)$">
   order deny,allow
   deny from all
</Files>

# Protect against Clickjacking
#Header append X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"

RewriteEngine on

# Force HTTPS
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=307,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/install.php$
RewriteRule install.php %1/install/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^client/login/?$ /login.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Do I just add the bottom line? Because that didn't seem to work either. :(

Comment: Are you getting 404 for `http://domain.com/billing/client/login/`? Is `/billing/client/` a real directory?

Comment: No 404; just seeing the standard page as if it wasn't being redirected (ie; the login page of the billing software). `billing` is a real directory, but `billing/client/` isn't.

Comment: Test the rule by placing `R` flag, i.e. `RewriteRule ^client/login/?$ /login.php [L,NC,R]`

Comment: No change after trying that.

Comment: Ah got it you have a catch-all rule also. See my updated answer now.

Comment: Thanks - got it working. Though had to add the `R` flag as I wanted it to show the place it got redirected to's correct URL in the location bar.

Comment: You're welcome, yes in that case adding `R` flag is right approach.